# Doubt in a very basic notation in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm starting to study algebraic geometry in a higher level and I found this notation:

[image]

What is exactly $s_{|V_i}$? When he says $s_{|V_i}$, for every $i$, can I rephrase this as $\rho_{UV_i} (s)=0$, for every $i$, where $\rho_{UV_i}:F(U)\to F(V_i)$?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes. I'm sure this notation is explained in the definition of presheaf.

Comment: @ZhenLin yes, you're right, but why this notation?

Comment: First, it is suggestive of restriction of functions, which is the most natural first example of sheaves.  Second, it is less cumbersome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $s \in \mathcal{F}(U)$, $s|_{V_i}$ is the notation for the restriction of the section $s$ to $V_i$. As you mention, it is the same as $\rho_{UV_i}(s)$.

The reason for the notation is that the motivation for a sheaf comes from functions (of some type) on the open set $U$. Then the restriction map is given by literally restricting the function to the open subset $V_i$.